# How to update GUI based on status

Tags: java, swing, events, jlist

I have a JList of object "Test" that is using a custom ListCellRenderer to show the name of the test and an icon next to it. The icon represents the status of the test (Warning, Ready, Running, Done). Test has a getStatus() method that returns an int. How can I let GUI know to repaint when the status of test changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key I believe lies with your ListModel. Presumably this extends AbstractListModel. The Model should be listening for or be notified of changes to the Test objects contained in the model and then the model's `fireContentsChanged(...)` method will need to be called. Doing this will notify the view, which listens to the model, that it must repaint a portion of itself.

One way to listen for changes is to make your status a "bound" property using a SwingPropertyChangeSupport object, and then have the model add PropertyChangeListeners to items it holds.

To implement this:

- The Test class should have a SwingPropertyChangeSupport object.
- The Test class should have both addPropertyChangeListener and removePropertyChangeListener methods that then add or remove the listeners to/from the SwingPropertyChangeSupport object.
- The Test class will have a `setStatus(...)` method that calls `firePropertyChange(...)` on the SwingPropertyChangeSupport object it holds.
- Give your ListModel an `addItem(...)` method that not only adds the Test object to the core of the model, but also adds a PropertyChangeListener to the Test object. You can and likely should use the same PropertyChangeListener for all items in the list.
- Of course this method will also call `fireIntervalAdded(...)`.
- Likewise, give this class a `removeItem(...)` method that removes the same PropertyChangeListener and also calls `fireIntervalRemoved(...)`.
- Consider giving your ListModel an inner class for the PropertyChangeListener, and in that class's propertyChange method, identify which Test object has changed via the `getSource()` method, find the index of this Test object, and then call `fireContentChanged(...)`.

Comment: I found SwingWorker actually does most of this for you :)